# How to create cutscenes in android app?

Tags: android

I want to create something like video-game or interactive-movie android application. Can i use video like cutscenes in `android` game? If i can, tell me please how to do it. Thanks! May be you can find the best way to make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you should use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) for your app (for example an `GameFragment` and an `CutsceneFragment`)

And to switch between those fragments use:

```
public void switchToFragment(String view) {
    Fragment frag;

    switch (view) {
        case "game":
            frag = new MyGameFragment();
            break;
        case "cutscene":
            frag = new MyCutsceneFragment ();
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.gameFragment, frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

This is what your game activity xml should look like:

```
<FrameLayout 
  android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:layout_weight="1" />
```

In your `MyCutsceneFragment` use a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)